# Bentley–Ottmann algorithm time complexity issue

Tags: computational-geometry

In the [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm), Regarding :

> Find the segments r and t that are immediately below and above s in T
>   (if they exist) and if their crossing forms a potential future event
>   in the event queue, **remove it**.

That means, every insertion of a segmant may lead to an intersection event deletion.

I am thinking what makes it stay within the said time complexity.

Is it valid to say that it is because i have up to n such insertions that would lead to up to n such deletions, which causes O(nlogn) operations at most hence the time complexity is not effected?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to doubt your explanation? Otherwise, there is no need ask for validation from this online community. Trust yourself more.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). What is the root cause of your uncertainty?  Is there some concept you don't fully understand? What prevents you from answering your own question?